# Algorithm help! Conditional and Iterative working together

Tags: mysql, algorithm

I'm a student needing help with a simple algorithm statement.  I'm wondering if you can nest a loop in a conditional statement.

Question: Mr. Furly owns 1 apartment that he rents. The usual rent is due every month except July and December; in those months Mr. Furly gives his renters a 50 percent credit. So they owe only half the usual amount.  Design a solution that would print 12 payment coupons.    Each coupon should contain the month (1 through 12), and the amount of rent due.
HINT: When complete with Part 1, the most efficient way of completing this algorithm should contain no more than 11 lines.  If you exceed more than 13 lines, you are doing it wrong. 
For example the coupon should read:
Month: 1  Rent: $$$$ (where $$$$ is the actual rent)
Month: 2  Rent: $$$$ 
and so on through Month 12.

I'm not getting any feed back from my instructor and I want to make sure I'm understanding correctly.  Any help is appreciated.

```
IF month = 7 THEN
   MonthCoupon = $$
ELSE
Count = Month 1
DO UNTIL Month = 7
  MonthCoupon = $$$$
   Display MonthCoupon
```

This is as far as I can get and I'm not even sure if I'm close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, I guess:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE calculate_rent(rent_per_month INT)
BEGIN
  SET month = 1;
  WHILE month < 12 DO
    IF month = 7 THEN SET rent = rent_per_month/2;
    ELSEIF month = 12 THEN SET rent = rent_per_month/2;
    ELSE SET rent = rent_per_month;
    END IF;

    SELECT month, rent;
    SET month = month + 1;
  END WHILE;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  The biggest question I guess I had is how you would insert the conditional statements and if you could nest them in the loop.

Comment: @BradWethington yes, you can nest them. You can use MySQL manual as a reference, for example: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/loop.html  If you have any concrete questions, you can ask them here, otherwise you might want to mark this question as answered